# Fix cross site scripting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, xss, cross-site

I have got a cross site scripting issue (reported by one of the tools)
I have a form on my screen with various fields.
Now if the user enters `<script>alert("1")</script>` tag for one of the field 1, browser is showing popup with value 1.

If user enters `<html>testString</html> or <script>alert("1")</script>` for field 1, it is being sent as encoded to server and retrieved back as encoded properly, but if the user does not modify field 1 containing these tags, but updates other fields like field 2, 3, field 1 is being messed up as it is being sent to server non encoded.

How can I fix this issue? Is there any standard way of fixing such issues ?

Also I use a Java resource where the form values are posted? So any changes to the same as well ?

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to replace the characters like '<' to its corresponding html entity equivalent like '&lt'. Its better to done it on server side since client side validation can be blocked by user. In javascript we can do like this.

```
document.write(htmlentities("<script>"));

function htmlentities(str) {
    var ret = str.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
       return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thx...and how can I decode it at the Java Resource layer (since i'll be sending the user input values to database finally)